# Would this be a correct cokernel

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

I'm a little confused on cokernels so I wanted to create an example and was hoping someone could check it to make sure I'm right.

Definition of cokernel:

If $ f: M \to N $ is a homomorphism of A-modules, then the cokernel of $f$, is the quotient $N/$image$(f)$

My 2 examples

$f:\mathbb{Z}_3 \to \mathbb{Z}_6$ such that $f(n)=2n \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}$ so the image is $[0,2,4]$

so would the  cokernel be $\mathbb{Z}_2$

and if we had $g:\mathbb{Z}_3 \to \mathbb{Z}_6 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_6$ such that $f(n,n) = (2n,2n) \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}$ what would the cokernel $\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$?

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to MSE!

Your notation is a little bit hard to follow, but it sounds like you're considering the map
$f : \mathbb{Z} / 3 \to \mathbb{Z} / 6$ defined by $f(n) = 2n$. Indeed, in this case the image of $f$ will be $\{f(0), f(1), f(2)\} = \{0,2,4\}$ and so the cokernel will be

$$
\mathbb{Z}/6 \big / \{0,2,4\} \cong \mathbb{Z}/2
$$

which it looks like you've correctly computed.

For your second question, it sounds like you're probably asking about the function $g : \mathbb{Z}/3 \to \mathbb{Z} / 6 \oplus \mathbb{Z} / 6$ defined by $g(n) = (2n,2n)$.

In this case, we can follow the same steps! We compute the image to be $\{(0,0), (2,2), (4,4)\}$, and you can check that the cokernel is

$$
\mathbb{Z}/6 \oplus \mathbb{Z}/6 \Big / \left \{(0,0), (2,2), (4,4) \right \} \cong \mathbb{Z} / 2 \oplus \mathbb{Z} / 2
$$

As an aside, which might make these computations easier, taking a quotient and taking a direct sum are both examples of [colimits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_(category_theory)#Colimits). It's a theorem of category theory that "colimits commute with colimits" in the sense that

$$
(M \oplus N) \big / (I \oplus J) \cong (M / I) \oplus (N/ J)
$$

Do you see how you might use this theorem in order to quickly compute the cokernel of $g$ using what we know about the cokernel of $f$?

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thank you for the help and the theorem at the bottom hopefully it can come into use :))